# scala repsep with new non empty line separator

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I've got 3 lines for parsing

```
John Smith
Nick Jackson
Liza Ashwood
```

i want to use `repsep` scala function with new line separator like this:

```
def parseLines: Parser[Map[String, String]] = repsep(parse, lineSeparator)
```

where `lineSeparator` is just **"\n"**

but sometimes there can be an empty lines without any names, just empty lines. in this case, i want to ignore this function

i was trying to use `opt(repsep)` which seems logical but this doesn't work

what can i do here? thx

Answer (score 1):

By empty lines, I'm assuming you can have data like this:

```
John Smith
            <-- empty line
Nick Jackson
Liza Ashwood
```

In this case, it means that there's two times the `lineSeparator`. So you can use the `rep1` combinator to tell that there should be at least 1 but there can be more line separators between each line of data:

```
def parseLines: Parser[Map[String, String]] = repsep(line, rep1("\n")) ^^ (ListMap() ++_ )
```

For example:

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers {

  override def skipWhitespace = false

  def parse(input: java.io.Reader) = parse(parseLines, input) match {
    case Success(res, _) => res
    case e => throw new RuntimeException(e.toString)
  }

  def parseLines: Parser[Map[String, String]] = repsep(line, rep1("\n")) ^^ (ListMap() ++_ )

  def oneOrMoreletters = "[a-zA-Z]+".r
  def line:Parser[(String, String)] = (oneOrMoreletters <~ " ") ~ oneOrMoreletters ^^ (t => (t._1, t._2))

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What if there will be no lines with text at all? Just 3 empty lines - how to turn off the function in this case?

Comment: @perc If you have 3 empty lines, it will return an empty map. I think it's a desirable output, no?